# How to return a Observable in promise function

Tags: observable, angular8, angular-promise

I have written an http interceptor in ionic + capacitor + angular. Since I'm using capacitor I'm accessing storage in promise function. But http interceptor excepts us to return HttpEvent Observable. Here is my code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpEvent, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';

const { Storage } = Plugins;

@Injectable()
export class Interceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor() { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        this.getItem().then(value => {
            const token = value['value'];
            if (token) {
                request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token) });
            }
            if (!request.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
                request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
            }
            request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json') });
            return next.handle(request).pipe(
                map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    }
                    return event;
                }));
        });
    }

    async getItem() {
        return await Storage.get({ key: 'revolt-token' });
    }
}
```

So far I have tried

```
return from(this.getItem()).pipe(map(data => {
            return next.handle(request).pipe(
                map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    }
                    return event;
                }));
        });
```

But it returns `Observable<Observable<HttpEvent<any>>>` but I want `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>`

Can someone help me identify how to return a Observable from a Promise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pipe switchMap instead of map
in return from(this.getItem()).pipe(map(data => {}));

Comment: Super excited to see you flesh this answer out.